# General formula for center and radius of the circle $\left|\frac b{z-c}-a\right|=r$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, mobius-transformation

Let us fix $a,b,c\in\Bbb C$ and $r>0$.

The set of complex numbers
$$
A:=\left\{z\in\Bbb C\;:\;\left|\frac b{z-c}-a\right|=r\right\}
$$
is circle if $|a|\neq r$, a line otherwise.

In fact $A=f(C)$ where $C$ is the circle $\{w\in\Bbb C\;:\;|w-a|=r\}$ and $f$ is the Möbius transformations $f(z)=\frac b{z-c}$, and it's well known that circles/lines are preserved under MT.

In the case of $A$ being a circle, does there exist general formulas to express its center and radius?

Comment: Actually $A = f^{-1}(C)$. Since $f^{-1}(0) = \infty$ and the points $0$ and $w_0 = a - a r^2/|a|^2$ are symmetric wrt $C$, the center of $A$ is $f^{-1}(w_0)$. The radius is $|f^{-1}(a + r) - f^{-1}(w_0)|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $\left|\frac b{z-c}-a\right|^2=r^2$, or

$$\left( \frac b{z-c}-a\right) \left( \frac{ \bar{b}}{\bar{z}-\bar{c}}-\bar{a}\right)  =r^2$$
Expand to get

$$|z|^2 -\left(c-\frac{\bar{a}b}{|r|^2-|a|^2}\right)\bar{z}
 - \left(\bar{c}-\frac{a\bar{b}}{|r|^2-|a|^2}\right)z
= \frac{|b|^2}{|r|^2-|a|^2} + \frac{a\bar{b}c + \bar{a}b\bar{c}}{|r|^2-|a|^2} - |c|^2$$

Then, express the equation in the standard form of a circle

$$ \bigg| z-\left(c-\frac{\bar{a}b}{|r|^2-|a|^2}\right)\bigg|^2= \frac{|b|^2r^2}{(|r|^2-|a|^2)^2}
$$

Thus, the center and the radius of the circle are respectively
$$c-\frac{\bar{a}b}{|r|^2-|a|^2},\>\>\>\>\>\>\>\frac{|b|r}{||r|^2-|a|^2|}$$

Comment: Thank you very much; I'm getting lost in finding out details from a paper...

Comment: @Joe - my pleasure